# Extract a row after a specific sequence of values pandas?

Tags: pandas, extract, data-mining

I have a pandas padaframe. I would like to extract each value which follows a specific sequence of values.

```
   ...                ...
    151                559
    152                578
    153                 87
    154              Cover
    155              House
    156                deg
    157               50.9
    158              Black
    ...               ....
```

In this case I would like to extract each number after the sequence "Cover","House","deg" in a new dataframe

Is anyone able to help me?
Cheers
Mick

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52791456/edit) to **show** us your desired output, and indicate what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have't tried anything so far as I really have not idea how to tackle the problem. In this case, the outcome will be 50.9 as it is followed by the three words "Cover", "House", "deg". The problem is that I have about 500 of this numbers

Comment: It was essentially extracted by 800 PDF files. I was able to extract all the data as a list. However, still need to extract the actual numbers